# Adblockers hiding a CSS class that's not an ad

Tags: html, css, twitter, adblock

I've had several site visitors report missing bits of text. Turns out they have ad blockers installed, and the missing text is linked to post a tweet with a custom CSS class name. Here's a sample of what disappears:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=xxxx&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx" class="tweet_quote">The text that disappears.</a>
```

Here is the definition for the class tweet_quote:

```
.tweet_quote {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(images/Twitter_logo_blue_32.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    transition: .2s;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.tweet_quote:hover {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #56aeec;
    background-image: url(images/Twitter_logo_white_32.png);
}
```

The Twitter_logo png is also blocked by the adblockers. The actual page URL is https://skeptoid.com/episodes/4516

Anyone see anything in there that might be triggering the ad blockers?

Answer (score 2):

Adblocks typically also block tracking widgets, which most social media sharing toolbars are.

`tweet` being in the class name is likely causing issues.

Comment: Tweet is probably it. Had this problem with several different sites using embedded Twitter and Facebook posts. It depends on the subscription the adblocker is using, though, as not all of them consider Tweets to be unwanted.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'll change it to something less suspicious.